# How to mock completion of a CompletableFuture in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, completable-future

I want to mock that some code is being called when a `CompletableFuture` has completed successfully.

I have this class:

```
public class MyClassImplementRunner implements Runnable {

    private final String param1;

    public MyClassImplementRunner(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Void> startAsync(String param1) {

        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            new MyClassImplementRunner(param1)).whenComplete(
            (response, throwable) -> {
                //some code when complete
            });

        @Override
        public void run () {
            //the runnable code
        }
    }
}
```

In my Junit (using Mockito and Java 8), I need to mock that

```
//some code when complete
```

is called when Future is completed successfully.

Could you provide some indications on how to achieve this?

Comment: Any solution to this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code you execute in `whenComplete` to a field and provide a constructor to replace it.

```
class Runner implement Runnable {

  private final String param;
  private final BiConsumer<Void, Throwable> callback;

  public Runner(String param) {
    this.param = param;
    this.callback = this::callbackFunction;
  }

  Runner(String param, BiConsumer<Void, Throwable> callback) {
    this.param = param;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  public void run() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(task).whenComplete(callback);
  }

  private void callbackFunction(Void result, Throwable throwable) {
    //some code when complete
  }
}
```

The test will look as follows:

```
class RunnerTest {

  @Test
  void test() {
    new Runner("param", (response, throwable) -> /* mocked behavior */).run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My first inclination is *not to mock this*: It looks like `startAsync` is a part of MyClassImplementRunner's public API, and that you should be testing these pieces together. In a test class like MyClassImplementRunnerTest, it makes sense to treat the system under test as MyClassImplementRunner without trying to split it up. Otherwise, it's very easy to lose track of *what you're testing*, including *what is real* versus *what is a mock*.

If there is any *external* condition that MyClassImplementRunner is looking for, you can mock that dependency, which would likely cause your CompletableFuture to return immediately; however, you've only shown us a single String parameter.

That said, it's possible that `startAsync` contains logic that you'd like to test exhaustively without a real MyClassImplementRunner. In that case, you could create an overload for testing, possibly with limited visibility or [test-only annotations](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) to indicate that it shouldn't be called in production.

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> startAsync(String param1) {
  return startAsync(new MyClassImplementRunner(param1);
}

/** Package-private, for a test class in the same package. */
@VisibleForTesting static CompletableFuture<Void> startAsync(Runnable task) {

  return CompletableFuture.runAsync(task).whenComplete(
      (response, throwable) -> {
        //some code when complete
    });
}
```

By splitting this up, you can now run `startAsync(new Runnable())` in tests to simulate an instantly-succeeding task, and run `startAsync(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })` to simulate an instantly-failing task. This allows you to test `startAsync` independently from MyClassImplementRunner.

It may not seem wise to refactor for testing or to introduce test-only methods, and this is a fair assessment: Purely speaking, MyClassImplementRunner *should* be tested exactly as consumers would run it, without mocking. However, if you're saying it is much more convenient in tests to run with a different Runnable than MyClassImplementRunner, you are in control of the code and you can prepare for this by including the appropriate flexiblity ("testing seam") in the code you control. In fact, if `startAsync` is a separate-enough method that it can take an arbitrary Runnable, you may choose to separate it out to be a separate method with separate testing.