# How to mock completablefuture.get()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

This is the method I'm trying to mock:

```
@VisibleForTesting
public List<Row> processRows2(CompletableFuture future) {
    List<Row> rows2 = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        DefaultAsyncResultSet beep = (DefaultAsyncResultSet) future.get();
        for (Row b : beep.currentPage()) {
            rows2.add(b);
        }
    }
    catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage() + " - Check thread pool resources are enough, may be too many queries in queue");
    }
    return rows2;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to test it with this (currently just trying to get it to run all the way to either success or failure):

```
@Test
public void processRows2test() {
    FeatureDaoImpl gar = new FeatureDaoImpl(connection);
    CompletableFuture L = new CompletableFuture();
    gar.processRows2(L);
}
```

It hangs endlessly. My guess is that the future.get() is where it's hanging; I'm not sure. But I'm not sure how to mock that. I've tried this:

```
@Mock
private CompletableFuture mockFutures;

@Before
    public void setUp() {
        try {
            Mockito.when(mockFutures.get()).thenReturn((AsyncResultSet) mockResultSetFuture);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

But this I feel is not correct. The try catch is because it yells at me about unhandled exceptions on the get(), so I don't know how to get around that.

I have also now tried this:

```
@Mock
final CompletableFuture<List<String>> mockedFuture = Mockito.mock(CompletableFuture.class);
```

With the following in the setup:

```
    Mockito.doReturn(new ArrayList<Row>()).when(mockedFuture).get();
```

But it still hangs endlessly.

I've seen these:

[How to mock completion of a CompletableFuture in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021545/how-to-mock-completion-of-a-completablefuture-in-mockito)
This one I don't understand what exactly it's trying to get me to do, and doesn't feel super applicable, because it's not a get method. I saw some examples here that have .get() in them... but none were mocked methods unfortunately, they were gets in the test itself: https://www.javatips.net/api/java.util.concurrent.completablefuture

EDIT: the code runs. It returns results. So it isn't that the actual method isn't returning a value - I know it does this, it's doing it in QA right now.

Comment: get will return when the future is completed.  There is nothing in your code completing the future.

Answer (score 5):

Your current `CompletableFuture` is not completed, so the `.get()` method hangs waiting for async completion that will never happen. You can use [CompletableFuture.completedFuture(value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) to create a `CompletableFuture` instance that will return the passed value when `.get()` is called on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` method here

```
@Test
public void processRows2test() {
    FeatureDaoImpl gar = new FeatureDaoImpl(connection);
    CompletableFuture L = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ArrayList<Row>());
    gar.processRows2(L);
}
```